# Disable Tango Tablet Updates

Tags: google-project-tango

We are shipping an app, which be on the Google Tango Tablet and made in Unity, within the coming weeks. We would like to lock down the current version of Tango on the tablet, since we have the application in a good state with the Hopak Version (version 1.53) release in May . How do we disable the tablet from automatically updating the Tango version on the Tablet?

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the updates of the Tango Core application.
The process to disable the updates is detailed in [this wiki](http://projectango.wikidot.com/wiki:tango-core)

Just in case, I would also do a backup of this application with the following command:

```
adb backup -apk com.google.tango
```